# Как перенести данные из таблицы mysql в другую таблицу?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД на сайте и ее копия на локальном сервере, на локальном изменено 990 строк, добавлены данные в несколько столбцов.
Какими способами(желательно простыми и безопасными) можно перенесте эти изменения в БД на сайте?

Comment: Утилитой mysqldump, входящей в комплект MySQL выгружаете таблицу и заливаете на сервере

Comment: Если есть phpMyAdmin, то совсем просто

Comment: @Egor, Просто это как?

Comment: @AFI19, 1. Зайти в `phpMyAdmin` на локальном сервере 2. Выбрать таблицу, которую вы хотите использовать (та, что с +990 строками). 3. Перейти на вкладку `Экспорт`. 4. Выбрать необходимые настройки или оставить по умолчанию и скачать таблицу. 5. Зайти в `phpMyAdmin` на сайте. 6. Перейти во вкладку  `Импорт`. 7. `Обзор->Выбрать скаченную БД->Вперёд`. Всё!

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRztW.png